# UIImage via https

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage, nsdata

I am trying to create a UIImage with

```
NSData *testData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

while the url looks like

```
https://myimage.gif
```

So, if I try to access the image via my firefox, it exists, so the url is valid. I do a check which looks somehow like

```
if(testData)
```

and log sth. into console, so it shows me, there is some data. However, creating an image like this doesn't work:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:testData];
```

I have no idea, what might be going wrong - appreciate any help!

Comment: just to be clear- url is a NSURL correct? Your code works fine if you use the same graphic from a http url?

Comment: Yes and no it's an NSURL and it doesn't work - it works the same way as above, if I use http:

Comment: self signed certificate? or not signed by one of the big players?

Comment: hm, what would that be exactly? In my app, I am logging in into a system with user credentials, and I extract data, depending on my logged-in / out status. Everything is fine, as far as I can see. I am wondering, why data exists, although I can't make an image out of it...

Comment: Data exists because its not an image data its connections response data. You cannot approve certificate therefore you receive response "forbidden". You CAN approve cert in normal http request though.